# Build a keyword list

Tags: elixir

I want to build a keyword list based on the presence of some values in a struct.

Currently I do it like this :

```
options = [timeout: @timeout, follow_redirect: true]
if proxy_conf.proxy_hostname do
  options = options ++ [proxy: {proxy_conf.proxy_hostname, proxy_conf.proxy_port}]
  if proxy_conf.proxy_username do
    options ++ [proxy_auth: {proxy_conf.proxy_username, proxy_conf.proxy_password}]
  else
    options
  end
end
```

Is there a simpler/nicer way to do it in Elixir ?

Comment: I'd suggest breaking each transformation of the list into a function, then composing them.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with different clauses:

```rb
defp set_proxy(options, nil, _), do: options
defp set_proxy(options, _, nil), do: options
defp set_proxy(options, proxy_conf, _) do
  options
  |> Keyword.put(:proxy, {proxy_conf.proxy_hostname, proxy_conf.proxy_port})
  |> set_auth(proxy_conf, proxy_conf.proxy_username)
end

defp set_auth(options, _, nil), do: options
defp set_auth(options, proxy_conf, _) do
  options
  |> Keyword.put(:proxy, {proxy_conf.proxy_username, proxy_conf.proxy_password})
end
```

And use it as:

```rb
set_proxy(
  [timeout: @timeout, follow_redirect: true],
  proxy_conf,
  proxy_conf.proxy_hostname
)
```

Please note, that this code also safe to execute even if `proxy_conf` is `nil`.